# How to integrate multiples sub querys with a sum and group by's

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to show the user info and multiple sums with their own "where and group by" qualifiers that refer to the user's balance of transactions.
I need to show the real balance, the bonus balances and the total balance.
It's simple to do it with one sum but I can't do it with multiple sums.

Here's my query with the 'real balance':

```
 SELECT v2_user.id, v2_user.username, v2_user.first_name,
 v2_user.last_name,     coalesce(SUM(v2_wallet.amount),0) AS 'Real balance' 
 from v2_wallet
 join v2_user
 on v2_wallet.user_id = v2_user.id
 WHERE TYPE NOT LIKE '%BONUS%'
 group by v2_wallet.user_id
```

I want to add 2 more columns to my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(v2_wallet.amount),0) AS 'bonus balance' from 
v2_wallet          
WHERE TYPE LIKE '%BONUS%' group by user_id

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(v2_wallet.amount),0) AS 'total balance' from v2_wallet group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed the condition inside the SUM instead of the WHERE clause, relying on the fact that booleans evaluate as 0 or 1.

```
SELECT v2_user.id, v2_user.username, v2_user.first_name, v2_user.last_name,        
SUM(v2_wallet.amount*(TYPE not like '%BONUS%')) AS 'Real balance',
SUM(v2_wallet.amount*(TYPE like '%BONUS%')) AS 'Bonus balance',
SUM(v2_wallet.amount) AS 'Total balance'
from v2_wallet
join v2_user
on v2_wallet.user_id = v2_user.id
group by v2_wallet.user_id
```

If v2_wallet.amount might be NULL, you need to use COALESCE(v2_wallet.amount,0) above.

If you don't like the looks of that, you can use IF instead of multiplication, like

```
SELECT v2_user.id, v2_user.username, v2_user.first_name, v2_user.last_name,        
SUM(IF(TYPE not like '%BONUS%',v2_wallet.amount*,0)) AS 'Real balance',
SUM(IF(TYPE like '%BONUS%', v2_wallet.amount, 0)) AS 'Bonus balance',
SUM(v2_wallet.amount) AS 'Total balance'
from v2_wallet
join v2_user
on v2_wallet.user_id = v2_user.id
group by v2_wallet.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :D i'll test it too

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly and gives me only the rows i need, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done MySql in a while. But generally this code should it. This is tested with SQL server sql syntax.

```
SELECT U.UserID,U.FirstName,T.TOTAL,B.BONUS 
FROM Users U 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT USERID, COALESCE (SUM(AMOUNT),0) AS TOTAL
            FROM WALLET
            GROUP BY USERID) AS T ON U.UserID=T.UserId
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT USERID, COALESCE (SUM(AMOUNT),0) AS BONUS
            FROM WALLET
            WHERE TYPE='BONUS'
            GROUP BY USERID) AS B ON U.USERID=B.USERID
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked but one thing, ¿how can i make user's which don't have any balance don't show up?
Sorry i think the answer below specified that i'll try
    COALESCE(v2_wallet.amount,0)

Comment: Change the first LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.